# Calling Javascript from the static index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

All I have in the public folder, index.html file of my rails is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jstester.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and all I have in the assets->javascripts folder is that I added a jstester.js file in it and all it has for now is just one line of code:

```
alert("fffsdfasdsad");
```

Everything else is just coming from the Rails defaults. 
Now when I run the rails server, should I see a message box? Because I don't see anything. 
What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assets served via the asset pipeline always come from `/assets`. The path to a JavaScript file served from the asset pipeline is `/assets/<file>.js`, not just `<file>.js`. Fix your `src` attribute:

```
<script src="/assets/jstester.js"></script>
```

Comment: aha, thanks. RubyMine autocomplete fooled me! it was recognizing the shorter path I had used. If I want to write a bunch of functions inside my javascript file, is there a way I can call whatever function I want from that JS file and not running the whole JS file?